# How can I map through a nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which looks like this:

```
const jewels = {
    infantry: {
        '3OayPUASk1JJFJwpKW7u': {
            id: '3OayPUASk1JJFJwpKW7u',
            name: 'Infantry ATK Jewel ',
            url: 'https://lordsmobilepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Infantry-ATK-Jewel.jpg',
            effects: ['Inf ATK 20%'],
        },
        '5N3y7DfjZwFTPxoyg3La': {
            id: '5N3y7DfjZwFTPxoyg3La',
            name: 'Terror Jewel',
            url: 'https://lordsmobilepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Terror-Jewel.jpg',
            effects: ['Inf ATK 10%', 'Inf DEF 10%'],
        },
        '7mOdjVqp9co87Ymkvk9F': {
            id: '7mOdjVqp9co87Ymkvk9F',
            name: 'Trojan Jewel',
            url: 'https://lordsmobilepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Trojan-Jewel.jpg',
            effects: ['Inf HP 15%', 'Travel Speed 5%'],
        },
    } etc ....
```

I would like to map the object so it would look like this for every item:

```
<h1>{infantry.name}</h1>
<img src='`${infantry.url}`'/> 
<h2>{infantry.effects}<h2/>
```

I did something like this:

```
const output = Object.values(jewels.infantry).map(({ name }) => (name));
```

My logic is obviously flawed here, I couldn't figure out how can I map multiple properties, I just mapped the `name`.
I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just destructure each property you need.

```
const output = Object.values(jewels.infantry).map(({ name, url, effects }) => {
    // return what you need
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on `jewels.infantry` to get all the key values as an array. Them use `map` or `for` on that array.

Since you have the id also as a field inside the object, you can use `Object.values()` directly as suggested by @Unmitigated.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
    const jewels = {
        infantry: {
            '3OayPUASk1JJFJwpKW7u': {
                id: '3OayPUASk1JJFJwpKW7u',
                name: 'Infantry ATK Jewel ',
                url: 'https://lordsmobilepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Infantry-ATK-Jewel.jpg',
                effects: ['Inf ATK 20%'],
            },
            '5N3y7DfjZwFTPxoyg3La': {
                id: '5N3y7DfjZwFTPxoyg3La',
                name: 'Terror Jewel',
                url: 'https://lordsmobilepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Terror-Jewel.jpg',
                effects: ['Inf ATK 10%', 'Inf DEF 10%'],
            },
            '7mOdjVqp9co87Ymkvk9F': {
                id: '7mOdjVqp9co87Ymkvk9F',
                name: 'Trojan Jewel',
                url: 'https://lordsmobilepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Trojan-Jewel.jpg',
                effects: ['Inf HP 15%', 'Travel Speed 5%'],
            },
        }
      };
        
        var output = Object.values(jewels.infantry).map(value => {
          return "<h1>" + value.name + "</h1><img src='`" + value.url + "`'/> <h2>" + value.effects + "<h2/>";
        
        });
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```